# Get median of groups in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame `df` and want to do is the following:

1. Sort the data by one variable
2. Group the data by the same variable
3. sum up the value of another column for every group
4. calculate the median value of all group sums

What I tried is:

```
median_old = df.sort_values('user_id').groupby('user_id')['total_play_seconds'].sum().median()
```

Although I believe my output is correct, the online course won't let me proceed, stating that the median value is incorrect.

Where did I go wrong?
As this is a task of an online course, I don't have a reproducible example, but I hope the matter is clear.

Comment: why do you sum before median?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the original question. I need the median of all group sums.

Answer (score 1):

I'll base my answer on the example taken from:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_groupby.htm

```
import pandas as pd

ipl_data = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings',
   'kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
   'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4 ,1 ,1,2 , 4,1,2],
   'Year': [2014,2015,2014,2015,2014,2015,2016,2017,2016,2014,2015,2017],
   'Points':[876,789,863,673,741,812,756,788,694,701,804,690]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)

print(df)
median = df.sort_values('Team').groupby("Team")["Points"].sum().to_frame()["Points"].median()
print(median)
```

As you can see, after the `groupby` and `sum` you get a pandas Series object and not a data-frame again. So you can't apply the `median` on the desired group. So I believe all you need to do is add `to_frame` and then calculate the `median` with the same logic you calculated the `sum`.

So in your case it should be:

```
median_old = df.sort_values('user_id').groupby('user_id')['total_play_seconds'].sum().to_frame()["total_play_seconds"].median()
```